# How do I access 127:.0.0.1:5000 on Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS (HVM), SSD Volume Type

Tags: amazon-ec2, python-3.6, flask-sqlalchemy, ubuntu-18.04

I just started studying flask and built a toy website to see how well I am doing. I have a flask website built in python 3.6 and I have tested it on my windows computer and everything goes very well. Now I want to host the website on an ubuntu ec2 instance. But first, I am testing if everything runs well on my ec2 instance and am stuck at trying to access port 5000 on my ec2 instance My app is currently serving on port `127.0.0.1:5000` of my linux server. I have tried to connect to `my.ec2.public.ip:5000` and `my.ec2.private.ip:5000` with no success. Could someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, your Flask app will listen only on localhost, you need to add `host` arg in `run` in make it listen to your actual server's IP.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80) #or whatever port you want your app to listen to.
```

To edit the security group of your instance, go to the EC2 instances page and slide to your extreme right, you will have Security Group column. Here click on the security group written in your instance and edit to add the port that you want to open.

Answer (score 0):

By default a new AWS instance would not allow port 5000 to be accessed, so you will need to modify the security group to allow access on that port. You do this thru the AWS console.

Comment: @EIBrennan I know your answer might be self sufficient but I am a newbie to ec2. How do I modify the security group on an already running instance?